# Application with multiple API data services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to design an Angular application that has components which register a callback function and a 'data request object' with an Angular service. This service basically keeps track of all the data request objects and which callback functions they refer to. Then, it performs long polling to make asynchronous calls to a RESTful API. When all the data comes in, the service decides which components need which pieces of data and calls into them with the results of the API call.

The problem I am having trouble wrapping my head around is that each component may need the data 'transformed' into a JSON object that prescribes to a specific format. For example, a chart component may require the data result to look one way, but a table component that may required the data result to look another way.

To make things even more complicated, I want to design my data service in such a way that the component can register for data from multiple different RESTful APIs.

Since I'm fairly new to Angular, I wanted to get help on some best practices for accomplishing this type of application. What I am thinking of doing is having a 'primary' data service that my components register with. The registration function will take as arguments a callback function and a data request object that will be in a format like so:

```
{
    "service": "apiService",
    "request": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then there will be a separate Angular service for each RESTful API. These sub-services will handle what to do with the data request object and correspond to the 'service' field above. The primary data service will then queue up requests to the sub-services on a long polling cycle. So the primary data service will look something like (NOTE: I am using ES6):

```
class DataService {
  constructor($q, $interval, $injector) {
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$interval = $interval;
    this.$injector = $injector;

    this.subscriptions = [];
    this.callbacks = [];

    this.poll();
  }

  poll() {
    let reqs = [];
    angular.forEach(this.subscriptions, (sub, i) => {
        let service = this.$injector.get(sub.service);
        let deferred = this.$q.defer();

        reqs.push(deferred);
        service.get(sub.request).then((result) => {
            this.callbacks[i](result);
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, (result) => {
            deferred.reject(result);
        });
    });

    this.$q.all(reqs).then(() => {
        this.$interval(poll, this.pollInterval || 10000);
    });
  }

  register(request, callback) {
    this.subscriptions.push(request);
    this.callbacks.push(callback);
  }
}

angular.module('DataService', []).service('DataService', DataService);
```

The piece that I am having trouble figuring out how to implement is the 'data transform' piece. As far as I can tell, there's really only two places I can see where this data transform can take place:

1. Inside the component
2. Inside the individual API services

The first way doesn't seem like a viable option to me as it breaks the common practice that components should be somewhat 'dumb.' The component should not handle transforming the data that the RESTful API returns: it should just use the data as-is.

But the second way also poses another problem, which is that each RESTful API service would have to have transform functions for every component type that I've created. This somehow doesn't seem 'clean' to me.

Is there another way I can design my application to achieve this goal? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: use angular's built-in event system.

```
//Constructor
constructor($q, $interval, $injector, $rootScope) {
 this.$q = $q;
 this.$interval = $interval;
 this.$injector = $injector;
 this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
 this.listeners = [];
 //No idea how its written in Angular2 but cleanup the event listeners when this is destroyed
 //Example in 1.5.x:
 //$scope.$on('$destroy', () => angular.forEach(this.listeners, l => l());
 this.poll();
}

//The new register method
register(ev, callback) {
 //When cleaning up - iterate over listeners and invoke each destroy function - see constructor
 this.listeners.push(this.$rootScope.$on(ev, callback));
}

//The new poll method
poll() {
    let reqs = [];
    angular.forEach(this.subscriptions, (sub, i) => {
        let service = this.$injector.get(sub.service);
        let deferred = service.get(sub.request).then((response) => {
         //responseToEventsMapper should map and parse response to list of events to fire.
         //Lets say the response is an authentication response for login attempt,
         //then the triggered events will be 'Auth:stateChange' and 'Auth:login' with
         //response.user as data. configure responseToEventsMapper upfront.
         let events = this.responseToEventsMapper(response);
         angular.forEach(events, event => this.$rootScope.$emit(event.type, event.data));
        });
        reqs.push(deferred);
    });

    this.$q.all(reqs).then(() => {
        this.$interval(poll, this.pollInterval || 10000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't realize that you could use $emit and $on this way (or that $on returns a deregistration function, especially handy). For the responseToEventsMapper, my question is still whether the mapper should be defined in the service or in the component? Say I have two APIs, apiA and apiB. They both return responses in a completely different formats, jsonA and jsonB. But the component requires data to be in a different format, jsonC. responseToEventsMapper should perform this transformation, but where is an appropriate place for it to be defined?

Comment: You can provide each subscriber with its own mapper during registration phase.